# How to deploy and link Nodejs backend to my GitHub React App?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, github, heroku, deployment

I've deployed my React-App to GitHub.

I need help though, because my React-App also has a backend that uses NodeJS/Express. And GitHub to my understanding only supports static, front-end tools (HTML, CSS, JS).

I understand that web hosts like Heroku and Google Cloud can host backends, but how do I link these to my Github React page?

Comment: How does your React App talk to your backend when its running on your laptop? Typically, they will communicate via REST API or web sockets.

Comment: I'm still a bit of a newbie so I'm afraid I'm not sure. I'm not using axios or react-router if that's what you mean. I'm utilizing news-api and pusher and all that.

Comment: Are you hosting the news-api or is it a public API?

Comment: It is a public api

Comment: And are you using pusher on your backend to update the front end (React) with new news stories?

Comment: Yes Im using pusher for that purpose I believe.